# startDrag causes ACTION_DOWN immediately followed by ACTION_CANCEL

Tags: java, android

I have an almost-full screen view with a horizontal RecyclerView (inside a custom view) at the base of it. I'm trying to drag elements out of the RecyclerView onto a view on the top half of the page. I'm trying to listen for both a tap as well as a drag but most of the time I can't get the touch listener to return anything other than ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_CANCEL.

A super annoying thing is that if I put break points and go into debug mode, it works fine. I get ACTION_DOWN -> ACTION_UP -> ACTION_DOWN -> ACTION_UP. Also sometimes it works on the first launch but then it won't work after that. If I comment out the v.startDrag() line, it works perfectly but then I don't get the shadow.

In the onBindViewHolder(), I'm setting a touch listener for each item as follows:

```
tv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        System.out.println(motionEvent.toString());
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item(groupId);
            String[] clipDescription = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
            ClipData dragData = new ClipData(groupId), clipDescription, item);
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadow(v);
            v.startDrag(dragData, shadowBuilder, v, 0); //commenting out this line lets me receive actions other than ACTION_CANCEL.
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

This is my DragShadow class.

```
private class DragShadow extends View.DragShadowBuilder {
    View view;
    private Point mScaleFactor;

    public DragShadow(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor.x / (float) getView().getWidth(),
                mScaleFactor.y / (float) getView().getHeight());
        getView().draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize,
                                       Point shadowTouchPoint) {
        View v = getView();
        int height = v.getHeight() * 2;
        int width = v.getWidth() * 2;
        shadowSize.set(width, height);
        mScaleFactor = shadowSize;
        shadowTouchPoint.set(width / 2, height / 2);
    }
}
```

If I add a log statement to print motionEvent immediately as the first line in onTouch, it is always ACTION_DOWN immediately followed by ACTION_CANCEL. It doesn't matter if I'm attempting a single tap or a drag:

```
07-14 18:39:00.699 11560-11560/com.whis.mobilize I/System.out: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=67.0, y[0]=77.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=109050123, downTime=109050123, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
07-14 18:39:00.705 11560-11560/com.whis.mobilize I/System.out: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=277.0, y[0]=1685.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=109050131, downTime=109050123, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
07-14 18:39:00.745 11560-11560/com.whis.mobilize I/ViewRootImpl: Reporting drop result: false
07-14 18:39:03.636 11560-11560/com.whis.mobilize I/System.out: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=49.0, y[0]=52.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=109053061, downTime=109053061, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
07-14 18:39:03.641 11560-11560/com.whis.mobilize I/System.out: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=439.0, y[0]=1660.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=109053067, downTime=109053061, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
07-14 18:39:03.712 11560-11560/com.whis.mobilize I/ViewRootImpl: Reporting drop result: false
```

I've tried adding adding RecyclerView item listeners, overriding onTouch() everywhere, adding requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true) everywhere, overriding onInterceptTouchEvent() everywhere, and nothing is working.

I've found other similar questions on here but they are all unanswered:

[Draggable View not moving, calls ACTION_DOWN then directly to ACTION_CANCEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884814/draggable-view-not-moving-calls-action-down-then-directly-to-action-cancel)

[EditText only calling ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_CANCEL sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173473/edittext-only-calling-action-down-and-action-cancel-sometimes)

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

EDIT

---

I realized this morning that when logging the touch events above, the ACTION_CANCEL is coming from another location. The x and y values of that touch event are drastically different from the x and y of the starting ACTION_DOWN. I think they correspond to the x and y where the shadow from the drag is in correspondence to the Activity. I still haven't been able to fix it though.

I've just gone through and added onTouchListeners which return false to every view I can access in my entire hierarchy and this behavior is still happening. If I override dispatchTouchEvent on my Activity, the events look fine so it's happening somewhere nested further down.

I've also disabled all animations and pull-to-refresh but no dice.

Comment: you said your problem goes away when you comment the last line huh?

Comment: Are you using this on an Emulator or a Real Device? Sometimes I have had issues with dragging on an Emulator.

Comment: @Elltz Yep, it's definitely something with the startDrag() line. I thought maybe the Shadow view that was being created was capturing the motionevent somehow but I haven't been able to stop that from happening.

Comment: @TheAnonymous010 This is on a real device. Nexus 5 on the latest version of Marshmellow.

Comment: @Nate Were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `view.startDragAndDrop()` and `view.startDrag()` should only be used when dragging between different containers/drop zones. I think this is the reason the method name changed (since there is no difference between them)

If you are simply trying to drag an `ImageView` around, there is no need to use `view.startDragAndDrop()`. For that, you can simply do the following:

```
class YourActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private var imageWidth = 0
    private var imageHeight = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val imageToMove = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.your_image)

        // get the size of the image, so we can adjust the touch coords later
        imageToMove.post {
            imageWidth = imageToMove.width
            imageHeight = imageToMove.height
        }

        imageToMove.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
            when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    // adjust the event coords based on size of the image
                    // 
                    // the touch coords is the middle of the image, so need
                    // to account for that
                    view.x = event.rawX - (pinWidth / 2)
                    view.y = event.rawY - (pinHeight / 2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are trying to drag a View from one ViewGroup to another, then you would want to use `view.startDragAndDrop()` and then set drag listeners on views that need to be "drag context aware"